# Is there a way to install separate versions of anaconda on two different user accounts (macOS)?

Tags: macos, anaconda, filesystems, python-3.6, user-accounts

I recently got a new job that's required me to use my personal computer (early 2015 Macbook Air, Mojave 10.14.2). Up till now, I've used my personal account for both work, school, and personal projects. Recently it's gotten so cluttered that I'd like to work from two user accounts, a personal one and a work one. When I created a new account, I tried to reinstall Anaconda, but when the installer finished, using

```
which conda
```

returned nothing. It looks like anaconda detected the anaconda installation in my personal user account, and didn't install.

I've tried copying the whole anaconda3 folder from my first account to my second and giving .bashrc the path in the second account, but all the paths inside the individual scripts still have the path to my old account.

I figure I could give my new .bashrc the path to my old installation, but I like putting packages that I write for work in the site-packages folder so I can access them quickly across the several directories where I need to use them, and I don't want to have to transfer files across accounts every time I update a package. Is there any clean way to get two independent anaconda installs for separate user accounts, or am I out of luck here?

Comment: Which Anaconda installer did you use, the '.dmg' or the '.sh' one? If you used the latter, then if you installed it and then immediately ran `which conda`, then it would almost certainly return nothing, because the modifications the installer made to your `.bash_profile` would not yet have been loaded.

Comment: Also, was your `anaconda3` folder in your home directory?

Comment: I used the .pkg one (which I think is the .dmg?) that you download from the anaconda website, and yes, it was in the home directory of my original account.

Comment: .pkg was what I meant, sorry. When you installed Anaconda in your second user account, did it leave a `anaconda3` folder in your home directory?

Comment: Ok, gotcha, no worries. It didn't leave a new folder in my home directory..